# Discrepancies in MS Graph Reporting APIs

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I've come across what appears to be some conflicting/missing information in the MS Graph Reporting APIs:

**Office365ActiveUsers (Detail)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/Office365ActiveUsers(view='Detail',period='D7')/content
```

[image: ActiveUsersDetail]

This returns 25 users, all of which have "License for Exchange" set to true, and 21 of them have a "Last Activity Date for Exchange". This date is the 9th March.

**MailboxUsage (Detail)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/MailboxUsage(view='Detail',period='D7')/content
```

[image: MailboxUsageDetail]

This only returns 24 users (admin@mod245278.onmicrosoft.com is missing). It also only has a "Last Activity Date" for 10 of them.

**MailboxUsage (Mailbox)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/MailboxUsage(view='Mailbox',period='D7')/content
```

[image: MailboxUsageMailbox]

This seems to say that there are only 24 mailboxes in the environment (presumably also missing the admin account), and that 5 were active on the 31st May.

**Questions**

1. How were there 5 active mailboxes on the 31st May when the last activity date for anyone was way back in March? Does it include messages received as "active"?
2. Why is the admin account missing from the last two API calls?
3. In the MailboxUsage (Detail) endpoint, why are only 10 of the mailboxes returning a "Last Activity Date" when 21 of them can be found in the Office365ActiveUsers endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Ian,

1. The following activities are counted as active mailbox:
   a.  MarkAsRead”
   b.  “MessageSent”
   c.  “CreateAppointment”
   d.  “SendMeetingRequest”
   e.  “AcceptedMeetingRequest”
   f.  “DeclinedMeetingRequest”
   g.  “CancelMeeting”
   h.  “MessageDelivered”.

However, only these 2 are counted when we compute Last Activity Date: “MarkAsRead” and “MessageSent”

On 31st May, those mailboxes received emails (MessageDelivered) without any other activities, so we treat them as active on 31st May but the LAD is not changed.

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing that up @Huy. Any thoughts on questions 2 and 3?

Comment: It appears the admin user doesn't have mailbox even though enabled for Exchange.

Comment: Get-Mailbox returns a mailbox for this user